# PostSharp - How to inject a method into a class?

Tags: postsharp, code-injection

I have some problem with PostSharp (I assume that problem can be solved by other library).
I have that scenario:

I must get all classes with name containing a word, e.g "Sth". I have that classes in my project (an example):

```
SthClass1.cs
SthClassBlabla.cs
SthClass3.cs
```

and I find that classes using `PostSharp`:

```
[assembly: TraceAttribute( AttributeTargetMembers = "Sth*")]
```

then, is it possible to inject (using aspect, PostSharp (?)) code for each found class ?

example:

```
 SthClass1 myObj = new SthClass1();
 myObj.ClassMethod1();
 myObj.ClassMethod2();
 myObj.InjectedMethod(); //that method belongs to the aspect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you use introduction.

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-14-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-1.aspx

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-15-e28093-Introducing-members-and-interfaces-Part-2.aspx