# How to automatically create (e.g.) singleton with c# using CodeDOM / T4 / PostSharp / whatever?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, metaprogramming, boilerplate

I'm looking for a way to automatically generate (e.g.) `singleton`, like:

```
[SingletonPatternAttribute]
public class Logger {
    public void Log (string txt) { /* do logging... */ }
}
```

as an attempt to eliminate boilerplate.

Does somebody know how it can be accomplished ? I know there are `CodeDOM`, `Reflection.Emit`, `T4` and so on. Also - there is (most notably) `PostSharp`, but I'd be really glad to see a real solution for the above challenge.

I can do the code-generation in the constructor, for instance, but compilation-time is obviously much better.

#### Edit:

The issue here is not the `Singleton`, but the generative / meta programming in `C#` - how to create code / eliminate boiler-plate in the best way - what kind of concrete examples there are ?

Comment: For this class of problems (not singleton, but more complex ones.., but if I understood correctly, singleton is only an example) I used many things in the past, from Reflection.Emit to IKVM (makes life easier) to MonoCSharp. It kind of depends, but when using attributes I like the Reflection/IKVM alternative, producing assemblies as a post-build step

Comment: But I am interested in hearing different approaches, so.. +1 :)

Comment: @dema80 - but where would you put the actual creation of the code using `Reflection.Emit` ? in the `class`'s constructor or someplace else ?

Comment: my approach was to build a separate executable (a separate project, to be clear) that took the original assembly (just compiled), walking through it, finding classes with attributes and build a "decorated" version of the assembly. But the target I had was slightly different, and in your case a AOP approach (PostSharp) could make more sense!

Comment: I have also used T4 on another project. All these techniques help in some way meta-programming, but they do not (or at least, I was not able) to bring them to the level you mention: based on attributes and actual C# source code, "transform" the C# code. Not easy, and interesting: I would like to know how others do it (without writing an actual C#->C# compiler, MonoCsharp or Roslyn)

Answer (score 2):

I do this exact thing for my logging class, using an IOC container and adding the scope when  mapping/binding the object.  For instance using Ninject, the binding would be:

```
Bind<ILogger>().To<Logger>().InSingletonScope();
```

Then in my classes where I want to use my singleton logger, I can use property injection:

```
[Inject]
public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't understand. I don't know Ninject, but what prevents me from defining another supposed-to-be-unique logger ? like: `public ILogger AnotherLogger { get { return new Logger; } }`

Comment: You could do that and you'd have another instance.  Using this technique wouldn't guarantee that other instances couldn't be created if developers in the team were unaware of IOC being used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Some time passed, but I have not read a satisfactory response, so I will write up what I have done in the past. I am still very interested in other approaches as well, as I feel that what I have achieved is not ideal and I myself would like to do better.

I have tried, in the past years, three of the four listed approaches for code generation of "enriched" classes:

- Reflection.Emit
- T4
- CodeDom (but I discarded this early, as it was at the time of my project, not complete!)

plus other three:

- IL rewriting using the Profiler API [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2007/03/06/creating-an-il-rewriting-profiler.aspx) (actually used)
- Interception using ContextBoundObject [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/02/10/contextboundobject-2-contexts-and-interception.aspx) (only tested)
- Embedding a C# compiler (Roslyn/MonoCSharp) [Here](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) and now also [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) (only researched, not atually used)

In general, I investigated all these tools to obtain some "weaving" of code, in an AOP way, starting from a something similar to the OP example: make classes and methods tagged with attributes "special", modifying their behaviour. At the time of my first project, AOP solutions for C# were not mature enough (but this may have changed meanwhile), so I cannot say anything about PostSharp, for example.
My purpose was, as I said, quite similar: based on attributes on classes and methods, add some additional code (and class members as well) to the classes. I ended using Reflection.Emit for the prototype, and IL rewriting using the Profiler API for the final thing.

The second project, for which I ended up using T4, was slightly different; it already used a code generator (more specifically, a parser generator), but we needed further (automatic!) modification of the generated source code.

### Reflection.Emit

I used the following approach: a class (let's call it MakeProxy) walked a given assembly, searching for attributes, and then emitted a new dll (a "proxy") which called the original assembly under the hood, providing the desired interface and behaviour to the user.

I actually used the class in a tool, a .NET executable, which was run by MS Build after the compilation pass.

The main disadvantage: references can be difficult to handle. You need to reference the automatically generated dlls, so you have to split your code in different projects, and you cannot even reference the original project(s) in a solution... it may be not acceptable. Also, you "see" (in the IDE) the original code too, and not the generated code; this may make debugging difficult.

### Profiler API

In this case, you do the same work as for Reflection.Emit, but you do not need to pre-build any "proxy"; code is injected at IL generation time (i.e. once, which is quite good performance-wise). You just write your (unmanaged) profiler DLL, and start your program under it. Your "profiler" will get notified of which functions are executed (or, better, which functions are JITed) and you can act accordingly.

The main disadvantages: you cannot modify the "structure" (methods, fields,...) of your classes (not easily); IL generation with unmanaged API is quite difficult (you have to take care of many things, and debugging when something goes wrong is a real nightmare!)
The main advantages: no modification is required to the original code (especially, no modification is required on the caller side - this is what lead me towards this solution in the end, given the requirements of that particular project).

### T4

I used T4 for a different project, but I can share my findings here. It is good for transforming text, but not really for transforming code: syntax becomes "weird" (you have code, and code inside the code to produce code... you get lost easily).

Main advantage: it is well integrated with the IDE and with the build system; you get intellisense support; it is easy to start with; you actually see what you are debugging

Personally, I would like to have (or build myself) something like T4, but that performs C# -> C# code transformation; in that way, you could have the advantages of the IDE (including intellisense on both the "original" and the "produced" thing) and the power of Reflection.Emit. You probably need to build both the C#/C# compiler, and a VS plugin to get all these goodies though.

One final note: today, I would use something more "advanced" than Reflection.Emit, like IKVM emit, or [Sigil](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/02/14/sigil-adding-some-more-magic-to-il/)

Comment: Your response is thorough. Thanks. My research led me to this additional solution - [PostSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345318/postsharp-how-to-inject-a-method-into-a-class) - which would've been the perfect solution, if this feature was free (it's only part of the "paid" version features). Still considering though...